# Ignore External Stylesheets

Tags: css

We are using a third party widget that uses a stylesheet from an external URL. It wasn't rendering the way I needed it to on mobile so I had to make some adjustments. For example, right now it's aligned left and I'd like it centered.

It looks like this:

```
<div>class="ts-starbar"</div>

div.ts-starbar{
  text-align: left !important;
}
```

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
   div.ts-star``bar{
      text-align: center !important;
    }
    }
```

Since I can't edit the original stylesheet, I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: You have back-ticks in your selector and the div is malformed. Is this your actual code or a typo in your question?

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is wrong. It should be:

```
<div class="ts-starbar"> </div>
```

Also, your second lot of CSS should be:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   div.ts-starbar{
      text-align: center !important;
    }
   }
```

Comment: Also, you should declare your own class and make the changes to the new class instead of using the naming structure of the third party  widget. So instead of using .ts-starbar call is something else of your choosing.

Answer (score 0):

The code is wrong. it should be like this:

**Html File :**

```
   <div class="ts-starbar"> </div>
```

**Css File :**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
       div.ts-starbar{
          text-align: center !important;
        }
       }
```

Comment: I put the CSS in my existing stylesheet, not in the HTML. I should have mentioned that. But thank you